# Find latest value in a comparison of data between 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have 2 tables in my DB and I want to compare values of 2 select queries Ive made on each one

Table 1: click_log

Query table 1:

```
SELECT *
FROM click_log
```

Table 2: km_articles

Query table 2:

```
SELECT km_article_no
FROM km_articles
WHERE  km_article_date <= "2017-10-31" AND km_article_status = "Published" AND km_article_view_count <= "5"
```

The columns I want to compare are table link_clicked for table 1 with km_article_no and I know I will find repeated matched, nevertheless from those repeated matches I want to find the latest one that I want to get from another column in table 1 called "when_clicked" that contains data information, not sure How can i put together those to queries and then narrow them down.

this is how the tables look like:

Table 1:

```
|link_clicked|when_clicked
     KB00001 | 2017-08-02
     KB00001 | 2017-12-02
     KB00002 | 2017-08-02
     KB00002 | 2017-09-02
     KB00003 | 2017-09-02
     KB00003 | 2017-09-02
```

Table 2:

```
km_article_no|km_article_ti|km_article_status|km_article_view_count|km_article_date
  KB00001    |outlook IOS  |  Published      |         5           | 2017-01-02
  KB00002    |outlook CSS  |  Published      |         4           | 2017-01-05
  KB00003    |outlook ZTE  |   Retired       |         3           | 2017-01-09
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The explanation is not as clear as it would be with such sample data.

Comment: Don't link to images. Some can't see them, some don't bother to click. The request was better before.

Comment: just added 2 snapshots of my tables with some sample data hope that would suffice

Comment: So you want to show all table2 rows, each with the latest related table1 date?

Comment: HeidiSQL is a GUI for various DBMS. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Im using mySQL, is a DB from a website I run in XAMPP

Comment: Sidenotes: You should call a thing always by it's name. If it's the article number, then don't call it link clicked. The string literal delimiter is the single quote (`'Published'`); a date literal is written `date '2017-10-31'`; a numeric value should have no quotes (`km_article_view_count <= 5`).

Comment: I understand the concern about the mismatch on the names, nevertheless link_clicked contains also other values different than articles as those are other links on my website thanks for the tips sticll catching up with SQL grammar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to show all `km_articles`rows, each with the latest related `click_log.when_clicked` date. So aggregate your `click_log` per `link_clicked` and find the maximum `when_clicked`. Then join this to `km_articles`.

```
select kma.*, cl.last_clicked
from km_articles kma
join
(
  select link_clicked, max(when_clicked) as last_clicked
  from click_log
  group by link_clicked
) cl on cl.link_clicked = kma.km_article_no
where kma.km_article_date <= date '2017-10-31'
  and kma.km_article_status = 'Published'
  and kma.km_article_view_count <= 5;
```

(If you also want to show `km_articles` rows that have no match in `click_log`, then change `join` to `left join`.)

Comment: The information I want to compare is km_article_no with link_click (like a Vlookup but displaying all matches, even the repeated ones) then after taking all those matches I want to take the unique value with the latest date registered on the "when_clicked" field

Comment: I Want first to filter the rows on km_articles with the query      
                                                                                                 
SELECT km_article_no
FROM km_articles
WHERE  km_article_date <= "2017-10-31" AND km_article_status = "Published" AND km_article_view_count <= "5"                              then take that result and compare the link_clicked column and get the latest related click_log.when_clicked date.

Comment: I don't see how this is different from what my query does. Get certain `km_articles` and add the latest related `click_log.when_clicked` date. Please edit your request and show the expected result, so I see how this differs from my query's result.

Comment: In fact it worked thanks a lot I thought querying at the end the km_articles table would affect the outcome but it doesnt.